# Pipe cerr to some file in c++ 17 build system for sublime text 3

Tags: c++, windows, sublimetext3, build-system

I have the following build system for c++ 17 in sublime text 3 running on a win 10 machine.

```
{
"cmd": ["g++.exe","-std=c++17", "${file}", "-o", "${file_base_name}.exe", "&&" , "${file_base_name}.exe<inputf.in>outputf.in"],
"shell":true,
"working_dir":"$file_path",
"selector":"source.cpp"
}
```

I need help to pipe the output of cerr stream to some file "errorf.in" present in same directory as source.cpp.

Also I want to know is there any way to capture and write the warnings and rte thrown by compiler like SIGSEGV to the same "errorf.in" file

Comment: Normally, one redirects standard error stream with `2>errors_go_here`. See if that works with your build system.

Comment: Also I want to know is there any way to capture and write the warnings and rte thrown by compiler like SIGSEGV to the same "errorf.in" file

Comment: `${file_path}` gives you the location that the current file is stored in, so `${file_path}/something` would put the file `something` in the same place as the current file.